# Вывод данных из JSON в несколько TextView

Tags: php, java, android, json

Что нужно переделать в коде, чтобы данные выводились не в ListView, а в TextView?

Привожу код SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

public static String JsonURL;
private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myBooks;
private static final String NAME = "name";
private static final String REIT = "reit";
private static final String BALANCE = "balance";
public ListView listView;

/** @param result */
public void JSONURL(String result) {

    try {
        //создали читателя json объектов и отдали ему строку - result
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        //дальше находим вход в наш json им является ключевое слово data
        JSONArray urls = json.getJSONArray("data");
        //проходим циклом по всем нашим параметрам
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm;
            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            //читаем что в себе хранит параметр balance
            hm.put(NAME, urls.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").toString());
            //читаем что в себе хранит параметр reit
            hm.put(REIT, urls.getJSONObject(i).getString("reit").toString());
            //читаем что в себе хранит параметр balance
            hm.put(BALANCE, urls.getJSONObject(i).getString("balance").toString());
            myBooks.add(hm);
            //дальше добавляем полученные параметры в наш адаптер
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SecondActivity.this, myBooks, R.layout.list,
                    new String[] { NAME, REIT, BALANCE, }, new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3 });
            //выводим в листвю
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.url);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    myBooks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    //принимаем параметр который мы послылали в mainActivity
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    //превращаем в тип стринг для парсинга
    String json = extras.getString(JsonURL);
    //передаем в метод парсинга
    JSONURL(json);
}}
```

И код PHP на JSON

```
<?php // серверная часть вывода json
$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if($login == "user" & $pass == "pass") {
?>      {
"data":[{
"name":"Jurij",
"reit":"150",
"balance":"50"
}]
}<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Ваша проблема не понятна. Не понятно что именно у вас затруднения вызывает и что вы попытались сделать для решения проблемы.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменил:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SecondActivity.this, myBooks, R.layout.list,
new String[] { NAME, REIT, BALANCE, }, new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3 });
            //выводим в листвъю
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

На

```
textView20.setText((CharSequence) hm.get("name"));
textView34.setText((CharSequence) hm.get("reit"));
textView60.setText((CharSequence) hm.get("balance"));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Не надо пересоздавать адаптер и назначать его на каждой итерации цикла. Надо сначала полностью сформировать список с данными и только потом, единожды создать и назначить адаптер.
2. Чтобы вывести в TextView, надо создать разметку с ним, найти программно его в разметке, сформировать строку для отображения и назначить её для TextView.

Comment: @Lobs, что именно у вас не получается - не понятно. В целом эта строка выглядит верно, но в ней я могу сходу увидеть 5 возможных ошибок разного вида. Например `NAME`, видимо, ключ, но не значение.

Comment: Программа работает корректно. Но она выводит данные в список, а мне нужно выводить данные в TextView.

Comment: @Lobs, это понятно. Не понятно что у вас затруднение вызывает. Вывести в список в разы труднее, чем в текстовое поле. Как вы смогли сделать первое, но не суметь второе?

Comment: Дело в том, что этот код я нашел в интернете как пример. А переделать его под свои потребности не получается. Хотелось бы знать, как начинающему программисту, что конкретно нужно убрать и что вместо него добавить. Или это нужно все перекодить?

Comment: @Lobs, вам надо изменить разметку, убрав из неё ListView и поместив взамен TexyView. Потом в него поместить данные из myBooks. Почитайте ещё где-нить к-л уроки про разметку и прочие базовые вещи. Если я просто вам напишу приложение - это же вам в изучении не поможет...

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш совет, но проблему мою это (пока) не решило. Про XML разметку я в курсе, и textview уже создал. А вот как поместить туда параметры? Пытался по всякому, например: txtName.setText("name: " + NAME);, не получалось. Я же не буду все свои варианты прописывать.

Comment: @Lobs, "не получилось" - это неинформативно. У вас ошибка и если да, то какая?